# What are the differences between the normal, hard and 'True West' difficulty modes?

Tags: call-of-juarez-gunslinger

I initially played the game in normal difficulty. After the first level, the game recommended that I play in 'hard' difficulty, instead. I would like to know how difficulty changes between the difficulty levels.

Specifically:

- Do enemy numbers increase, or will their numbers stay the same?
- Or do enemies just have more hit points or deal more damage? Know by how much they are increased?
- Any enemy AI behavior differences? Do they become 'smarter'?
- Any other differences between the difficulty levels?
- Any difficulty differences when you're playing a New Game Plus (separate from the difficulty level you chose to play the New Game+ in)?

In 'True West' mode, most of the HUD gets removed. Aside from that, are there other difficulty differences between hard and 'True West' difficulty?

Comment: I do not know anything about CoJ:G personally but after a bit of research I now know that people are pretty disappointed in that difficulty setting and didn't seem to find much difference in that vs Hard (obviously the HUD is a pretty big part).

Answer (score 1):

I know, the question is more than 3 years old, but in case someone wants to know, here is what i found out after searching the internet with no success and testing it myself:

- the enemy count stays the same
- normal enemies stay at the same hit points, except bosses, which get significantly more (i would guess hard: 50% more, true west: 100% - 150%)
- the higher the difficulty level, the more do enemies stay behind their cover, apart from that i couldnt observe different ai behavior
- i guess the enemy is dealing 50% more damage on hard and on true west what feels like 100% or even 150% more damage, in addition their shots are much more precise on hard and true west, but i cant say exactly how much
- the new game+ feels exactly the same, no changes in difficulty
- as you said, in true west mode the hud, crosshair and hints get removed

I hope this helps